# Using Google Maps Directions API With Google Drive Scripts

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to use some of the more advanced google maps directions API features with my google drive scripts.  I signed up for a developer key, but when looking at the Resources -> Advanced Google Services menu inside of Google Drive Scripts, the directions API isn't listed there.  I haven't been able to find another way to enable the key/features.

Answer (score 0):

Its indicated in the [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) page of the Appscript documentation that if its not listed in the `Resources -> Advanced Google Services`, you can still call those [APIs externally](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external). The documentation indicates that you'll have to call the services using the `URLFetchApp` class.